# Couldn't find executable named publish below /home/jcardenasc93/catkin_ws/src/publisher

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm trying to create a simple publisher program following the tutorial 'A gente introduction to ROS' Jason M. O'Kane. So the problem is that when I try to compile the program `rosrun publisher publish` I get an  error: Couldn't find executable named publish below. My CMakelist.txt is modified as in the tutorial and I add the excecutable in it:

```
## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(publish pubmes.cpp)
## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(publish ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I don't think that was bash configuration because in another example I could compile the 'Hello ROS' program without any problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204680/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-publish-below-/home/jcardenasc93/catkin_ws/src/publisher/) by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2015-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So the problem is that when I try to compile the program `rosrun publisher publish` I get an error

*Compiling* and *running* are two different things.

`rosrun` will try to *run* your program, but you'll have to have *compiled* it first, which is typically done with `catkin_make`.

Make sure you have build your workspace first, *and* have sourced the correct `setup.bash`, as explained in the book.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on 2015-03-11**:
That's you right y forgot it... Now it's everything OK... Thank you a lot